# Very simple left align document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, document-classes

Is this document class an article? I can't get it left aligned. [`Haldane.pdf`](http://markoseslija.net/seslija/Promotion_files/Haldane.pdf)
How can I achieve this simple style?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  what do you mean should be left aligned?  the title and author?  (the text is usually left aligned except for paragraph indents.)

Answer (score 1):

The document looks like it was produced with one of the KOMA-script document classes, possibly `scrartcl`.

You raise a separate question: How does one typeset a document with left-justified (AKA ragged-right) text? For that, I suggest that you (i) load the package `ragged2e` with the `document` option set, i.e., issue the command `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` and (ii) issue the command `\RaggedRight`. Both commands should be inserted in the preamble of your document.